# My SQL query in NOT condition not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My SQL query in NOT condition not working. (NOT u.paymentmethod=3) Please tell me how to make a query for this perfect.  Thanks in advance

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(u.`refered`) 
         FROM user u 
         WHERE u.refered = user.user_id 
         AND  u.paymentmethod = 2 and NOT u.paymentmethod=3  ) as ref,
       user_id,
       paymentmethod 
from user  
HAVING ref < 6
```

Comment: Without letting us know what you want to achieve and what is your sample data, will be difficult to help, please post that.

Comment: instead of using NOT use <> or != symbol  i.e `u.paymentmethod<>3 `

Comment: I guess you don't need that not condition, you have already compared `u.paymentmethod = 2` that won't allow `u.paymentmethod = 3` itself.

Comment: i want get userid's who's paymentmethod 2 not 3, but with this query it's show userid paymentmethod 3 also.which i don't want.

Comment: Of course you get all payments in your result, since the main query has no WHERE clause. However, the count (from the sub-query) won't include them.

Comment: So How to do this @jarlh. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong syntax for `not` change your query as below:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(u.`refered`) 
         FROM user u 
         WHERE u.refered = user.user_id 
         AND  u.paymentmethod = 2 and u.paymentmethod != 3  ) as ref,
       user_id,
       paymentmethod 
from user  
HAVING ref < 6 and user.paymentmethod = 2
```

**EDIT**

Also your query doesn't need `u.paymentmethod != 3` condition as `u.paymentmethod = 2` is already there

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(u.`refered`) 
             FROM user u 
             WHERE u.refered = user.user_id 
             AND  u.paymentmethod = 2) as ref,
           user_id,
           paymentmethod 
    from user  
    HAVING ref < 6 and user.paymentmethod = 2
```

Comment: Remove `and u.paymentmethod != 3` as `u.paymentmethod = 2` indicates it will be 2 not any other value.

Comment: Thanks for your Great answer @B. Desai sorry but it's output same. i want get userid who's paymentmethod = 2 not 3. Thanks

Comment: will you show your sample data? because if `paymentmethod =2` then it wont be `3`

Comment: Hello @B.Desai Please check this link in this payment method 3 also show but i want show only paymentmethod 2 not 3. Thanks

 https://pste.eu/p/MZ5G.html

Comment: Great Bro Thanks it's worked like a charm. Will you please tell me where i am getting wrong. ??

Comment: your condition was from inner query only however user id can match with payment method = 3 also from outer query. So you need condition for outer query also. Hope you get it

Answer (score 0):

That's a hell of a way to write it to avoid a self join...

```
SELECT COUNT(u.`refered`) as ref
       a.user_id,
       a.paymentmethod 
from user a
left join user u
  on u.refered = a.user_id
  and u.paymentmethod = 2 
  and u.paymentmethod <> 3 -- not needed, but might as well include it
group by user_id, paymentmethod
HAVING ref < 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change just not condition.like below code.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(u.`refered`) 
         FROM user u 
         WHERE u.refered = user.user_id 
         AND  u.paymentmethod = 2 AND u.paymentmethod<>3  ) as ref,
       user_id,
       paymentmethod 
from user  
HAVING ref < 6
```